# How to disable scrolling while using UIPanGestureRecognizer on a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

In my app I have a draggable `UIView` contained in a `UIScrollView` so that I can zoom it. This moving `UIView` has a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` but if I zoom in first and then I try to move the `UIView`, that does not happen and instead the scrolling is performed as if the UIPanGestureRecognizer is not detected.

[image]

This is my associated method to the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`:

```
func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if (self.panRec.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began) {
        self.scrollViewContainer.scrollEnabled = false
    }

    else if (self.panRec.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
        self.scrollViewContainer.scrollEnabled = true
    }

    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self)
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        self.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
            y:view.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self)
    self.updatePinsPosition()

}
```

As you can see I try to disable scrolling when the the user taps in the draggable `UIView` and reactivate it at the end but it doesn't work. Where am I making a mistake? What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
So explain myself better, I have a `UIScrollView` which contains a `UIView` and inside this last there are some other `UIViews` acting as pinch, the azure ones. I decided to use a further `UIView` as container so that the sub views are zoomed all together by scrolling. So, my zoom code is the following:

```
class PhotoViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
  @IBOutlet weak var containerView: ContainerController!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    self.scrollView.delegate = self
    self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
    self.scrollView.flashScrollIndicators()

    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0

  }

  func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return self.containerView
  }

}
```

Comment: can u add your zooming code here

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasBhati sorry for the late, I've just added the code you required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have to override this method of Scrollview Delegate in your ViewController for both zooming and panning

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {

   scale *= [[[self.scrollView window] screen] scale];
   [view setContentScaleFactor:scale]; // View which you want to Zoom & pan.
   for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
    [subview setContentScaleFactor:scale]; // all the Container Views
    }
 }
```

Hope it will help you to solve your problem.